# Returning unique_ptr variable returns an error

Tags: c++, pointers

I came across a weird problem.  I get an error message in setGetDog() method when written this way:

```
class Dog
{
    public:
    void bark() { std::cout << "Bark!" << std::endl; }
};

class test
{
    public:
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> setGetDog()
    {
        if (!dog_)
        {
            dog_ = std::make_unique<Dog>();
        }
        return dog_;
    }

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> dog_;
};

int main()
{
    auto testClass = std::make_unique<test>();
    auto dog = testClass->setGetDog();
}
```

Error is like this:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Dog; _Dp = std::default_delete<Dog>]'
```

But when I change the implementation to:

```
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> setGetDog()
    {
        return std::make_unique<Dog>();
    }
```

It works just fine.

What is the matter with `dog_`?
I do not understand why the error states that it is deleted when in fact `test` is still alive when the method was called (and so `dog_` as well).

I know I can write this some other way but I'm specifically curious on why behavior is like this on this implementation.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: most probably the compiler cannot apply [return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) when its not certain what will be returned (as a result of the if statement). So it has to attempt a copy, which is not allowed for unique_ptr.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

Comment: Try changing the signature to `const std::unique_ptr<Dog>& setGetDog()`.

Comment: P.S. `std::unique_ptr` says something about the ownership of the pointer that make it inappropriate as the return value of a function in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different types of value categories/situations that objects have that affects how there are returned from a function.  Lets look at the rvalue category first.  When you do

```
std::unique_ptr<Dog> setGetDog()
{
    return std::make_unique<Dog>();
}
```

`std::make_unique<Dog>()` returns by value making the return object an rvalue.  That means that when the compiler returns the object it will implicitly move it. (the compiler can also elide the copy but that doesn't matter for this discussion)  Since the object is moved you don't have any issues since `std::unique_ptr` is movable.

The second case is when you have an lvalue, but it is a function local object.  If you had

```
std::unique_ptr<Dog> setGetDog()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Dog>();
    return ptr;
}
```

Here `ptr` is an lvalue but it is going away so we can call it an xvalue(expiring value).  With xvalues, when you return them the compiler tries to move it, since moving it is a safe operation in this case.  If the move operation does not exist/is not viable, then the compiler falls back to copying.  Since `std::unique_ptr` is movable, it gets moved without error.

The last case is when you have a plain lvalue like you have with

```
class test
{
    public:
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> setGetDog()
    {
        if (!dog_)
        {
            dog_ = std::make_unique<Dog>();
        }
        return dog_;
    }

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> dog_;
};
```

Here, `dog_` is a member of the class, not a object local to the function.  This means the only thing the compiler can do is try and make a copy.  Since you can't copy a `unique_ptr`, you get an error.  You would need `return std::move(dog_);` for it to compile, but if you did that `dog_` in the class would be empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you just return the `unique_ptr` then [return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) can be applied. This is because the `unique_ptr` can actually be constructed at the address of the unique_ptr instance in the calling function. The compiler allows this as no copying is occurring.

When you add the if, the function may or may not be trying to return an existing instance. It's a runtime decision. An existing instance wont have the opportunity to be constructed where the calling function wants it and so must be copied.

`unique_ptr` has a deleted copy constructor to preserve the unique part of its contract, so the code does not compile.

Depending on your needs you may want to use a `shared_ptr`, use `std::move` (mistake probably, it empties the `unique_ptr` inside your class) or use value semantics to copy the actual object and not the pointer to it.